# Dialog with pattern dim

Tags: android, dialog

I have made a dialog that looks like a speech bubble that I want to use to help the user of the app when clicking on certain views. Now I'd like to dim the entire app except for the view that is clicked (highlighting the entire width would also be fine)
An example:
[image]

Here I'd like the lower Lorem Ipsum to be highlighted (or rather, the rest of the app to be dimmed). What is the best way (fewest lines of code) to accomplish this?

Edit for clarification: The view I'd like to highlight is NOT part of the dialog layout and I want it to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);  //dialog layout
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;  //adjust it 
mDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
mDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
mDialog.show();
```

here `mDialog` is your dialog.

Comment: Thanks. However, this dims everything including the view I'd like to highlight.

Comment: i used it in ,my code though..and it works well..your dialog background is black  . maybe it is mixing with the dim content.you can try adjust the dimAmount...

Comment: Also you can try adding elevation property in your dialog layout..to make it on top of the view